# Installing Charm++ on macOS Mojave

Tags: c++, fortran, openmpi, macos-mojave, charm++

I am trying to install Charm++ on the latest version of macOS 10.14. Following this http://charm.cs.illinois.edu/manuals/html/charm++/A.html, when I try and do `./build charm++ netlrts-darwin-x86_64 --with-production -j8` I get this error:

```
configure: error: in `/Users/youssefmoawad/Downloads/charm-6.9.0/netlrts-darwin-x86_64/tmp':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** [headers] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------
Charm++ NOT BUILT. Either cd into netlrts-darwin-x86_64/tmp and try
to resolve the problems yourself, visit
http://charm.cs.illinois.edu/
for more information. Otherwise, email the developers at charm@cs.illinois.edu
```

When I try the installation using the alternative method, through Spack; first off I have to install Spack: https://spack.io. That fails however when I do the `spack install hdf5`, getting:

```
Error: InstallError: OpenMPI requires both C and Fortran compilers!

/Users/youssefmoawad/Downloads/spack/var/spack/repos/builtin/packages/openmpi/package.py:337, in die_without_fortran:
    334        # avoid delayed build errors in dependents.
    335        if (self.compiler.f77 is None) or (self.compiler.fc is None):
    336            raise InstallError(
>>  337                'OpenMPI requires both C and Fortran compilers!'
    338            )

See build log for details:
   /Users/youssefmoawad/Downloads/spack/var/spack/stage/openmpi-3.1.3-6owrpmticip3filnaljkrsyl3zlonwea/openmpi-3.1.3/spack-build.out
```

When I disregard that and try to install Charm++ anyway, using `spack install charmpp`, I get:

```
Error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

 /Users/youssefmoawad/Downloads/spack/var/spack/repos/builtin/packages/charmpp/package.py:173, in install:
    170        # here.
    171        options = [
    172            os.path.basename(self.compiler.cc),
>>  173            os.path.basename(self.compiler.fc),
    174            "-j%d" % make_jobs,
    175            "--destination=%s" % prefix,
    176        ]

See build log for details:
/Users/youssefmoawad/Downloads/spack/var/spack/stage/charmpp-6.8.2-g3j72njzqjejhutygtdksfdy6sp524us/charm-v6.8.2/spack-build.out
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, but I think it has something to do with Fortran compilers, in which case could I get some help on which compiler to install?

**Update**
I have tried installing the `gfortran` compiler and it installed successfully, but I still encounter the above errors.

Comment: This ste is not for softwre recommendation. Doesn't the roject state in the documentation which comiler versions do they support?

Comment: @VladimirF not really that I could find. I tried installing `gfortran` but no luck.

Comment: take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/running-open-mpi-on-macos/

Comment: @Oo.oO I've managed to successfully install and test OpenMPI,  but unfortunately it hasn't helped.

Comment: @YoussefMoawad but is it the very same message or is it something else now? Take a look at config.log. Sometimes, messages are miss leading. Try to look for `C compiler cannot create executables` inside configure script and extract the part that is there. By looking at what is called there, you may find that something else is causing the issue.

Comment: Yup, it's the same message. I tried to use the `mpicc` compiler instead of `gcc` or `clang` but it says that it doesn't support it. I found the part inside configure that says that but I can't tell what the issue is.

Comment: Possibly related...? (e.g., may need to edit compilers.yaml to add gfortran paths?) https://github.com/spack/spack/issues/7147, https://github.com/spack/spack/issues/3146, https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct build line. The issue might be some incompatibility with the C++ compiler, like Charm++ passing incorrect flags to the compiler. gfortran shouldn't be needed for regular builds. It would be helpful if you can show any errors displayed in `config.log`. If it turns out to be a bug, you might want to report it in the mailing list or the forum (https://charm.discourse.group).

Another way to install Charm++ on macOS is using charm4py: `pip3 install charm4py`. It comes with Charm++ compiled as a shared library but is used through a Python interface so this may not be what you are after.